# How to pass Dyanmic SQL Query in Python

Tags: python, pyodbc

Can Someone help me how to create a dynamic SQL Insert Query using Python. Please find the below query.

```
'Insert into January2022Tr (Name, Bank_Name, Amount) Values (Recharge, xxxx, 2000)'
```

I am getting following error message:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
> Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Recharge'. (207)
> (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
> Server]Invalid column name 'xxxx'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
> Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Bank_Name'. (207)")
> python-BaseException

I found that `VALUES()` part does not include with quotes `""`,  that's the reason that insert into query is not working as expected. How to add quotes - `""` inside the `VALUES()`?

Comment: You need to use single quotes for text literals in SQL Server: `sql = ("Insert into January2022Tr (Name, Bank_Name, Amount) Values ('Recharge', 'xxxx', 2000)")` and `cursor.execute(sql)`.

Comment: And you need to check if the `Bank_Name` column really exists in the `January2022Tr` table.